# How to call different functions based on recently clicked buttons?

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following code with two buttons "Button 1" and "Button 2". I want to have 2 different texts in my assigned paragraph. If "Button 1" is clicked, the text should show "Button 1 was clicked." and if "Button 2" is clicked, the text should show "Button 2 was clicked." And if we click no any button, the text should show "No button was clicked."

```js
function btnSelector() {
  var x = document.getElementById("btn1")
  var y = document.getElementById("btn1")
  var z = document.getElementById("demo")
  if (x.click == "true") {z.innerHTML = "Button 1 was clicked."}
  
  else if (y.click == "true") {z.innerHTML = "Button 2 was clicked."}
  
  else {z.innerHTML = "No button was clicked."}
}
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
<button id="btn1" value="enter"/>Button 1</button>
<button id="btn2" value="enter"/>Button 2</button><br><br>
<button id="proceed" onclick="btnSelector()">Proceed</button>
```

The problem I'm facing is that my code isn't detecting any click on both of my button. Need your help!

P.S: It's just a sample code I wrote here. In my main project I need calling different functions based on recently clicked buttons but I hope if this I find solution to this sample code, it'll definitely help solving the problem in my main project.

Comment: Concept is all wrong. You need event listeners for each button

Comment: You need to assign the function to all the buttons, not just one. Use `function btnSelector(e)` so you have access to the ClickEvent, then compare like `if (e.target.id == "btn1") ...`

Answer (score 1):

That is not how event handlers work. You might want to read about them on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events

Take a look at the code below to get a hint.

```js
function btnSelector(btnID) {
  const z = document.getElementById('demo')
  switch(btnID) {
    case 0:
      z.innerHTML = "No button was clicked."
      break
    case 1:
       z.innerHTML = "Button 1 was clicked."
       break
    case 2:
       z.innerHTML = "Button 2 was clicked."
       break
  }
}
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
<button id="btn1" value="enter" onclick="btnSelector(1)">Button 1</button>
<button id="btn2" value="enter" onclick="btnSelector(2)">Button 2</button><br><br>
<button id="proceed" onclick="btnSelector(0)">Proceed</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

This type of problem is a good candidate for [event delegation](https://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate). This approach lets you add a single delegated event listener (on a parent element) instead of many event listeners (one per `button`).

This technique is only possible due to the nature of [event propagation (bubbling and capturing)](https://javascript.info/bubbling-and-capturing) in the DOM.

```js
const demoEl = document.querySelector('#demo');
const getButtonDescription = e => {
  if (e.target.tagName === 'BUTTON') {
    return e.target.textContent;
  }

  return 'nothing';
};

document.querySelector('#container').addEventListener('click', e => {
  const desc = getButtonDescription(e);
  demoEl.textContent = desc ? `You clicked ${desc}` : '';
});
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <p id="demo"></p>
  <button id="btn1" value="enter">Button 1</button>
  <button id="btn2" value="enter">Button 2</button><br><br>
  <button id="proceed">Proceed</button>
</div>
```

You can see in my example that I have enclosed all your HTML in a `div` with `id='container'`. I added the event listener to the the container `div` and nowhere else:

Comment: Thanks but when we click the button "Proceed" it states "You clicked nothing."

Comment: You need to update your question if that's not correct because it is unclear. When should it say "No button was clicked"

Comment: I updated my code to what I think makes sense, but you have to let me know.

Answer (score 0):

More of the same, this is how i would do it:

```js
var btns = document.getElementsByTagName('button'); // set variable for the buttons
for (var i=0; i < btns.length; i++) { // loop the buttons
  btns[i].addEventListener('click', function() { // add Event Listener
 document.getElementById('demo').textContent = 'Button ' + this.id + ' clicked! '; // Write the click message
  });
}
```

```html
<p id="demo">No button was clicked</p>
<button id="btn1" value="enter"/>Button 1</button>
<button id="btn2" value="enter"/>Button 2</button><br><br>
<button id="proceed">Proceed</button>
```